# Why the displayed color is not the expected color in VTK?

Tags: c++, colors, vtk

The problem is that RGB values I pass to vtkProperty don't generate the expected color. For example slateblue identified by RGB (146, 110, 218) appears as white.

Here is the relevant code :

```
vtk.vtkLineSource line = new vtkLineSource();
line.SetPoint1(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
line.SetPoint2(50, 50, 0.0);

vtkPolyDataMapper mapper = new vtkPolyDataMapper();

mapper.SetInput(line.GetOutput());

vtkActor lineActor = new vtkActor();
lineActor.SetMapper(mapper);

double r = 146.0;
double g = 110.0;
double b = 218.0;

vtkProperty property = new vtkProperty();
property.SetColor(r, g, b);
lineActor.SetProperty(property);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of this behavior is that VTK uses normalized color values.

So the solution is very simple : we have to divide the value by 255

```
[...]

double r = 146.0 / 255.0;
double g = 110.0 / 255.0;
double b = 218.0 / 255.0;

vtkProperty property = new vtkProperty();
property.SetColor(r, g, b);
lineActor.SetProperty(property);
```